# list elements padding in iOS sencha touch

Tags: css, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am having problem with displaying list elements in iPhone [image]
here in the image 'Black' is overlapped with itemdisclosure icon. I tried to style it using text-align: "right" but didn't find any difference. Any help would be appreciated

here is my list code

```
itemTpl : [
    '<p style="font-family:arial;color:black;font-size:20px;">{DESCRIPTION}</p>',
    '<div style="font-size: 0.75em; color: darkgray">SKU:{CODE}</div>'
].join(''),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be having this problem because sencha adjust the itemdisclosure icon based on text.

Anyway, just give width to `p` tag

**CSS**

```
.description{
 font-family:arial;
 color:black;
 font-size:20px; 
 width:90%; // reduce as you wish
}

.code {
 font-size: 0.75em; 
 color: darkgray;
}
```

**List code**

```
itemTpl : [
    '<p class="code ">{DESCRIPTION}</p>',
    '<div class="description">SKU:{CODE}</div>'
].join(''),
```

Well, you still want inline style

```
 itemTpl : [
    '<p style="font-family:arial;color:black;font-size:20px; width:90%;">{DESCRIPTION}</p>',
    '<div style="font-size: 0.75em; color: darkgray">SKU:{CODE}</div>'
 ].join(''),
```